# Running script in Anaconda´s Spyder4 Python does not see already imported modules in the console

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

After installing the newest version of Anaconda with Spyder4 I encountered strange behavior when running Python scripts. When running scripts as a file .py (via Run file (F5)) Python does not see the already imported modules. However, when I run the lines separately or type the commands in the console Python "sees" them. In the previous version Spyder3 I could run multiple scripts and use all previously loaded modules unless I reload the console.

If someone could help what changed in Spyder4 vs Spyder3.

[Example: python doesn´t see already imported numpy when running scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAc6i.png)